# How can I efficiently store hand-drawn lines(canvas)?

Tags: javascript, canvas, storage

**Background**

I'm making a simple online drawing app so that I can practice my JS and canvas skills.  It's going really well, with the ability to draw freely, and also the ability to draw straight lines.

**How my drawing app works**

It registers mouse and touch events, which handle all of the drawing and saving.

Here's some example code:

```js
var tools={
    "pencil":{
        "started": false,
        ... (some data used by the pencil tool),
        "start":function(e){
            if(currentTool!=="pencil")return;
            // Make sure that the selected tool on the toolbar is the pencil
            
            // code for mousedown/touchstart
            tools.pencil.started=true;
        },
        "move":function(e){
            if(!tools.pencil.started)return;
            // code for mousemove/touchmove
        },
        "end":function(e){
            if(!tools.pencil.started)return;
            // code for mouseup/touchend
            tools.pencil.started=false;
        }
    },
    "other tools":{
        ...
    }
};

// And here would be a function which adds the mouse and touch events
```

Here is my pencil tool:

```js
var tools={
    pencil:{
        started:false,
        start:function(e){
            if(currentTool!=="pencil")return; // Make sure the pencil tool is selected
            e.preventDefault();
            e=e.clientX?e:e.touches[0]; // Allow touch
            context.beginPath(); // Begin drawing
            context.moveTo(e.clientX-50,e.clientY); // Set the position of the pencil
            tools.pencil.started=true; // Mark the pencil tool as started
        },
        move:function(e){
            if(tools.pencil.started){ // Make sure the pencil is started
                e.preventDefault();
                e=e.clientX?e:e.touches[0];
                context.lineTo(e.clientX-50,e.clientY); // Draw a line
                context.stroke(); // Make the line visible
            }
        },
        end:function(e){
            if(tools.pencil.started){
                e.preventDefault();
                //tools.pencil.move(e); // Finish drawing the line
                tools.pencil.started=false; // Mark the pencil tool as not started
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Ignore the `-50` parts (they're just to adjust with the sidebar).  This works, but doesn't save to `localStorage`.

**Problem**

TL;DR: I need to save everything on the canvas into some storage (I was currently using `localStorage` but anything would work, although I would prefer usage of the client-side only).  I can't figure out how to efficiently store it, where 'efficiently' means both fast and accurate (accurate as in it stores the whole line).  Lines can be stored, but hand-drawn items I haven't figured out yet.

Explanation:

When the user resizes the window, the canvas resizes to the window size (I made this happen, not a bug).  I was able to make it that when you resize, it first saves the drawings onto a temporary canvas and then, after the main canvas resizes, redraws them back.  But there's a problem.  Here's an example to make it clear:

1. You open the draw app and fill the screen with drawings.
2. You open DevTools and some of the drawings get covered
3. When you close the DevTools, then those drawings are gone.

The reason is because since the canvas got smaller, the drawings that went off of it were lost, and when it came back to the original size, they weren't visible (because they're gone).  I decided to save everything to `localStorage` so that I can retain them (and also for some more features that I may add).  The lines are working (since they only need to say, "I am a line, I start at x,y and end at x,y".  That's it for a line of any size.  But for hand-drawn images, they can go anywhere, so they need to say, "I am a pixel, I am at x,y", but many times for even remotely complex images.

**Attempted solution**

Whenever they move the mouse, it saves to a variable which then updates to `localStorage`.  The problems with this is that if you go fast, then the lines isn't complete (has holes in it) and `localStorage` is storing a *lot* of text.

**Question**

How can I *efficiently* store all of the user's hand-drawn (pencil tool) images (client-side operations preferred)?

Comment: You could rasterize it to an image.

Comment: @David: I had the same idea as you (a long time ago).  I *could* make it an image, but I'm not sure if `localStorage` will be fine with humongous `data:` URIs.

Comment: localStorage is capped to 5MB, so it depends on how much you're trying to store. You don't necessarily *have* to store it in localStorage though. Especially if you're just trying to hold onto it until the window.resize event is finished.

Comment: @David: I didn't mention it but I was thinking that a refresh should keep the image still there.  I was also thinking of using blob URLs but I wasn't sure about how long they would last and if they would make sense.

Comment: Maybe you could look into saving it as SVG, since you already have all the coordinates during drawing, and as a vector format it takes a much less memory space. Although, this approach might conflict with the whole idea of using canvas.

Comment: @Gil: That's a good idea.  My focus wasn't to force canvas use, just to learn how to do graphics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to consider the target use of this app and work backwards from it.

If you're doing something like a MS Paint drawing app, storing a canvas as a bitmap may be better. To deal with cropping issues, I would suggest that you use a predefined canvas size or a setup stage (with a maximum size to prevent issues of saving to LocalStorage).

If you're worried about image size being restrictive due to memory cap, you can also utilize compression.

ie.

```js
canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.5);
```

will compress the image and return a string that will be localStorage friendly

If, on the other ✋, you are building something more like an excalidraw app, where you want to maintain the ability to edit any drawn object, then you'll need to store each object individually. Whether you use canvas or SVG doesn't really matter imho, but the SVG can make it a bit easier in the sense that the definition of how to store each element is already established, so you don't need to re-invent the wheel, so-to-speak, just need to implement it. Use of SVG doesn't necessarily preclude you from using canvas, as there are a couple SVG-in-canvas implementation, but if you're doing this as a learning project (especially for canvas), it's likely not the route you want to take.

Comment: I wanted something more like Excalidraw, so SVG seems like a good option.  Gil also  suggested it in the comments on my question.  Seems like I'm going to be doing SVG now!